# Why does return false in event handler doesn't work on mobile?

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, return-value

Can someone tell me why is this working on desktop browser and not working on mobile ?

```
case 'homepage':
        $('#locate').on('click', function () {
            var lat, lng, query;
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            if (navigator.geolocation) {

                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    lat = position.coords.latitude;
                    lng = position.coords.longitude;
                    query = '?latitude=' + lat + '&longitude=' + lng;
                    var newUrl = url + query;
                    window.location.href = newUrl;

                });
                return false;
            }
        });
        break;
```

After investigating this i found out that this code works, however i made some corrections because its acting strange on mobiles so we better provide some feedback to users in case we don`t get coordinates

```
case 'homepage':
        $('#locate').on('click', function () {

            var lat, lng, query;
            var url = $(this).attr('href');

            function geoError(error) {
                var errors = {
                    1: 'Permission Denied',
                    2: 'Position unavailable',
                    3: 'Request timeout'
                };
                alert(errors[error.code] + ": means we can`t determine your position");
            }

            function geoSuccess(position) {
                lat = position.coords.latitude;
                lng = position.coords.longitude;
                query = '?latitude=' + lat + '&longitude=' + lng;
                alert(query);
                var newUrl = url + query;
                window.location.href = newUrl;
            }

            var options = {enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 0, timeout: 6000};

            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError, options);
            }
            return false;

           }
        });
        break;
```

Both versions of code works if user enabled location on his mobile, but if he didn`t second version is better because he will get respond

Comment: check e.stopPropagation()

Comment: Are you sure it's working on **all** desktop browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE)?

Comment: I need this to work only on mobile devices, i tried various combination with e.PreventDefault and e.StopPropagation and e.stopImmediatePropagation and still doesn`t work. When i remove return false it sends me to link but without query.

Comment: if e.stopPropagation() doesn't work, it's because you don't have `navigator.geolocation` and you think the return false is the problem when you never reach that part of the code.

Comment: First make sure you tried `e.stopPropagation()` not `e.StopPropagation`. And when you did try this, did you include `e` in your function()?

Comment: this make sense, i will remove if statement and check it out.

Comment: I have test the code by using iPhone, it correctly works.

Comment: @KNaito tnx mate, maybe something is wrong on my phone, i`m using Nexus 4 and testing on Chrome and Next Browser and still nothing, when you click on locate link it should take you to url with with parameters in url your.html?latitude=lat&longitude=lng is that what you getting ?